# MySQL query is hiding results when grouping by multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the total hours worked by employees from January to November broken down by county. I am ONLY interested in employees who worked anywhere in the last 60 days.

When I run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a.empid) AS EMPL_ID, a.cnty AS COUNTY, SUM(a.hours) AS HRS 
FROM timesheet_lines AS a
WHERE a.date >= '2014-1-1'
AND a.date <= '2014-11-30'
GROUP BY EMPL_ID
HAVING MAX(a.date) > '2014-10-18';
```

I get the correct number of hours, but it is not broken down by county.

When I add the grouping by county like THIS query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a.empid) AS EMPL_ID, a.cnty AS COUNTY, SUM(a.hours) AS HRS 
FROM timesheet_lines AS a
WHERE a.date >= '2014-1-1'
AND a.date <= '2014-11-30'
GROUP BY EMPL_ID, COUNTY
HAVING MAX(a.date) > '2014-10-18';
```

It breaks it down by county, but it removes counties and the hours worked in those counties for employees who did not work in that particular county in the last 60 days.

How can I add the breakdown by county, and still get ALL the hours worked?

Here is an example of the data I want to pull for one employee:

```
EMPL_ID COUNTY  HRS
------- ------  ---
5461    ONTARIO 105
5461    WAYNE   1182
5461    YATES   24
```

Here is what I get when I group by EMPL_ID only:

```
EMPL_ID COUNTY  HRS
------- ------  ---
5461    ONTARIO 1311
```

That has the correct total hours, but it does not properly break down by COUNTY.

Here is what I get when I group by EMPL_ID *and* COUNTY:

```
EMPL_ID COUNTY  HRS
------- ------  ---
5461    ONTARIO 105
5461    WAYNE   1182
```

Now it breaks down by COUNTY, but it ignores YATES county I think because the employee did not work in YATES county in the last 60 days.

Comment: try taking out the having clause. the row may well be there, but because of the grouping it's changing the max() value and therefore getting dropped by the having filter.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need `distinct` when you are using `group by`.

Second, the problem is your `having` clause.  You need to filter on the employees but report on employee/county combinations.  That requires a subquery of some sort.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT a.empid AS EMPL_ID, a.cnty AS COUNTY, SUM(a.hours) AS HRS 
FROM timesheet_lines AS a
WHERE a.date >= '2014-01-01' AND a.date <= '2014-11-30' AND
      a.empid IN (SELECT EmpId
                  FROM timesheet_lines tl
                  GROUP BY EmpId
                  HAVING MAX(date) > '2014-10-18'
                 )
GROUP BY EMPL_ID, COUNTY;
```

EDIT;

When `in` takes too long, replace it with a `join`:

```
SELECT a.empid AS EMPL_ID, a.cnty AS COUNTY, SUM(a.hours) AS HRS 
FROM timesheet_lines a JOIN
      (SELECT EmpId
       FROM timesheet_lines tl
       GROUP BY EmpId
       HAVING MAX(date) > '2014-10-18'
      ) e
      on a.EmpId = e.EmpId
WHERE a.date >= '2014-01-01' AND a.date <= '2014-11-30'
GROUP BY EMPL_ID, COUNTY;
```

Actually, I should have written it this way to begin with, but I didn't realize how large your data is (and I think the `IN` version is easier to read).

Comment: This may or may not work, but it was running for over 2 hours, so I stopped it to try another solution. Still looking for one. Evidently my timesheet_lines table is too big to run inside the interior SELECT statement. That seems to be what is making it take so long.

Comment: I tried to mark this as helpful, but it says I need 15 reputation first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with, and it worked great:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tsltemp 
SELECT empid
FROM timesheet_lines tl
GROUP BY empid
HAVING MAX(date) > '2014-10-18';


SELECT a.empid AS EMPL_ID, a.cnty AS COUNTY, SUM(a.hours) AS HRS 
FROM timesheet_lines AS a
WHERE a.date >= '2014-01-01' AND a.date <= '2014-11-30'
  AND a.empid IN (SELECT empid FROM tsltemp)
GROUP BY EMPL_ID, COUNTY;
```

This was amazingly faster. Thank you, Gordon, for getting me on the right track!